# Xbox Live over Mac connection sharing using a Socks Proxy

Tags: ssh, lan, xbox360, socks-proxy, connection-sharing

I've recently moved into an apartment with a managed wifi connection. Everything is heavily proxied and most ports besides 443 & 80 are blocked.

I have a personal server running at my parents house with openssh running on port 443. I can ssh into the server no problem and I have set up a socks proxy to route all my traffic over the ssh connection. This works fine for all local applications.

I want to share my internet connection from my mac to my Xbox. Not for playing games online since the latency would be too bad, but just to download updates for games, update my gamertag etc

I can connect my Xbox to my Mac without issue, however the Xbox does not seem to be aware of the socks proxy and tries to use the connect over the lan which has ports blocked. Thus the connection to Xbox live fails.

What do I need to do to make the Xbox use the socks proxy? From my searching I have read that I may need to locally set up a transparent proxy. But I'm not sure.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the local host as the proxy setting for your xbox 360... I'm not entirely sure if it works this way, but if it does, let me know. I'm trying to get a similar set up going.

Comment: No unfortunately the xbox won't work that way on the network I'm on. It's heavily locked down. Though it may on yours